# Recursive determination of all solutions from a cube tower

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have to solve a task to determine all solutions from a cube tower in Java.

**Task:**
Four cubes with colored surfaces(red, blue, green, yellow) are piled on each other and are rotated, so that none of the four colors appear twice on each side of the walls.
I have to develop a system, that will **recursively** determine **all** solutions for the cube tower. 
(compare to a puzzle called **"Instant Insanity"** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Insanity)

Iteratively it's relativly easy to solve this puzzle, but the recursive approach is very difficult in my opinion.

**Cube-Class:**

```
private String[] colour;

public Cube() {
    this.colour = new String[6];
    for(int i = 0; i < colour.length; i++) {
        colour[i] = colourRead();
    }
}
```

I also got two function to rotate the cube horizontally and vertically, a get-function for the colour and and a function to read in the colour for the cube.

**Cube-Tower-Class:**

```
private Cube[] cube;
private ArrayList<String> solutions;
private int solutionCounter = 1;

public CubeTower() {

    this.cube= new Cube[4];
    this.cube[0] = new Cube();
    this.cube[1] = new Cube();
    this.cube[2] = new Cube();
    this.cube[3] = new Cube();
    this.solutions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I also got a get-function for the cube and a function to test, if there are duplications of colours on one side of the cube-tower.

I've got no clue, how to write a function to determine all the solutions recursively. Maybe anyone has suggestions how to solve the puzzle. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On a technical level, all you need to convert an iterative solution to a recursive one (for any problem) is conversion of local variables (from outside of, but used in the loop) to method parameters. Then you simplify them further as you can (and can even wrap the information in an object if it's an excessive amount).

Comment: show us the iterative approach you have working

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Haven't coded it, but it basically has to do with the position of the different cubes:
The cubes have 24 different positions, that they can lie. You can change the positions through a rotate-Function. 
So at every position cube 1 lies, you now rotate cube 2 into its 24 positions, for each position cube 2 lies, you rotate cube 3 and so on. So in total you have 24^3 different sollutions of the whole cube tower. After every rotation of cube 4 you check, whether the solution of the tower is legitimate. If yes, you add it to the solutions, if not, the loop continues working.

Comment: @Rogue thanks for the help, i will try that

Comment: if you can get the iterative approach to work i'd be happy to help you with the recursive approach. Recursive approaches will tend to take longer than iterative approaches because of the overhead involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pseudo-code for the recursive approach.

```
function findAllSolutions(cubeTower):
    if cubeTower is None:
        cubeTower = []
    solutions = []
    if length(cubeTower) < 4:
        for each cube in possible cube rotations:
            cubeTower.push(cube)
            solutions.appendAll(findAllSolutions(cubeTower))      
            cubeTower.pop(cube)
    else:
        if (isValidSolution(cubeTower)):
            solutions.push(copy of cubeTower)
    return solutions
```